# How to call game Update from another form

Tags: xna, c#, windows-forms

I have three projects in one solution:

- a form with some tool (see it as a level-editor), in which there is PictureBox where I want to redirect drawing of the game.
- My game, with some methods and its Update/Draw methods:
- A launcher (where I can start the game or start the level-editor)

```cs
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) {...}
 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {...}
```

This is the launcher's "Open game in editor mode" button code:

```
private void cmdEditorMode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Game1 game_instance = new Game1(true))
    {
        using (MapEditor form = new MapEditor())
        {
            form.Show();
            form.game_wrapper = new GameWrapperForLevelEditor(
                game_instance,
                form.pctSurface.Handle,
                form,
                form.pctSurface);
            game_instance.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that:

- `true` in Game1 constructor is just a bool used to tell the game to open it in editor mode.
- `GameWrapperForLevelEditor` is another class used to make the form of the level editor and the Game itself in relation.

In particular (to draw inside the pictureBox drawSurface):

```
 public GameWrapperForLevelEditor(
            Game1 game,
            IntPtr drawSurface,
            System.Windows.Forms.Form parentForm,
            System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox surfacePictureBox)
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            //...
            //...other things
            //...
            graphics.PreparingDeviceSettings +=
                new EventHandler<PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs>(graphics_PreparingDeviceSettings);
        }
```

and:

```
 void graphics_PreparingDeviceSettings(object sender, PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs e)
 {
    e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.DeviceWindowHandle = drawSurface;
 }
```

This is the launcher's Main code:

```
using System;
namespace Launcher
{
#if WINDOWS || XBOX
    static class MAIN
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Launcher_form form = new Launcher_form())
            {
                form.Show();
                //Creo un'istanza del picture_box_render all'interno del form
                form.picture_box_render = new launcher_picture_render(form.pctLauncher.Handle);
                form.picture_box_render.Run();
            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Note that:

- I use here another game (`picture_box_render`) because in my launcher's form I put a picture box where I want to run an animation that is rendered as another game loop.

Finally the draw part:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
    spriteBatch.Draw(game.LastRender, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

**My problems are:**

- `game_instance.Run();` (up) gives me this error (translated from italian, so sorry):

> Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not valid operation Use
>   Form.ShowDialog.

- `game.LastRender` is Always empty because the game never run. `game.LastRender` is just a `RenderTarget2D` where Game1 draw method draws the game.

As a solution, I thought that I may don't `game_instance.Run();`, but just use `game.Update(...)` and `game.Draw(...)` inside my wrapper class. The problem is that these two methods are `protected`, and if I try to set them `public` it says me that I can't.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [**official sample**](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1). It demonstrates *exactly* how to get XNA to output inside WinForms.

Any other method for doing this is almost certainly wrong and will either fail outright, or fail unexpectedly in certain circumstances.

---

To use the official sample, you will have to extricate your existing code from the `Game` class. This means you must implement your own `Draw` and `Update` methods, your own timing mechanism (you can use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`), and possibly a replacement for `GameComponent` (if you use it).

I find it helps to separate your game into three projects: A shared "**engine**" XNA library, a "**game**" XNA project, and an "**editor**" WinForms project.

Then use the "game" and "editor" simply as thin wrappers for setting up the graphics device and calling your own `Update` and `Draw` methods on your own class in your "engine" project.

If you want a launcher, it's probably best to create a fourth project to contain it. I'd simply have it invoke the selected executable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A last question: inside another project, what's the instruction to invoke an executable?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`.